# 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonElement' is not an attribute class on simple POCO

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, mongodb-csharp-2.0

This is my POCO:

```
private class Widget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("x")]
    public int X { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Id: " + Id + " X: " + X;
    }
}
```

And I get an error on the `BsonElement` attribute:

[image]

I'm using:
Framework: .NET v4.5,
References: MongoDB.Driver.dll v2.0.1, MongoDB.BSON.dll v2.0.1
IDE: Visual Studio Premium 2012

Seems to work fine for the guy in [this video](https://youtu.be/XpHsKDcWlrM?t=390).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it. This `using` declaration was required:

`using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;`